# How To Count Rows Based on Values of Two Variables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am fairly new to SSIS, and now I have this requirement to exclude weekends in order to do a performance management. Now I have created a calendar and marked the weekends; what I am trying to do, using SSIS, is get the start and end date of every status and count how many weekends are there. I am kind of struggling to know which component to use to achieve this task.

So I have mainly two tables: 
1- Table Calendar
2- Table History-Log

Calendar has the following columns: 
1- ID
2- date
3- year
4- month
5- day of week
6- isweekend

History-Log has the following:
1- ID
2- Status
3- startdate
4- enddate

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide tables and columns names?

Comment: Why do you need (or want) to use SSIS for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an SSIS user, so apologies if this answer does not help, but if I wanted to get the result you describe, based on some test data:

```
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (
    ID INT,
    [Date] DATETIME,
    [Year] INT,
    [Month] INT,
    [DayOfWeek] VARCHAR(10),
    IsWeekend BIT
)

DECLARE @HistoryLog TABLE (
    ID INT,
    [Status] INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20100101', @NumberOfYears INT = 10
DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);

INSERT INTO @Calendar
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d) AS ID,
        d AS [Date],
        DATEPART(YEAR,d) AS [Year],
        DATEPART(MONTH,d) AS [Month],
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY,d) AS [DayOfWeek],
        CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,d) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsWeekend

FROM
(
  SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) AS y;

INSERT INTO @HistoryLog
SELECT 1, 3, '2016-01-05', '2016-01-20'
UNION
SELECT 2, 7, '2016-01-08', '2016-01-25'
UNION
SELECT 3, 4, '2016-01-01', '2016-02-03'
UNION
SELECT 4, 3, '2016-02-09', '2016-02-10'
```

I would use a query like this to return all of the `HistoryLog` records with a count of the number of weekend days between their `StartDate` and `EndDate`:

```
SELECT  h.ID, 
        h.[Status], 
        h.StartDate, 
        h.EndDate, 
        COUNT(c.ID) AS WeekendDays
FROM @HistoryLog h
LEFT JOIN @Calendar c ON c.[Date] >= h.StartDate AND c.[Date] <= h.EndDate AND c.IsWeekend = 1
GROUP BY h.ID, h.[Status], h.StartDate, h.EndDate
ORDER BY 1
```

If you wanted to know the number of weekends, rather than the number of weekend days, we'd need to slightly amend this logic (and define how a range containing only one weekend day - or one starting on a Sunday and ending on a Saturday inclusive - should be handled). Assuming you just want to know how many distinct weekends are at least partially within the date range, you could do:

```
SELECT  h.ID, 
        h.[Status], 
        h.StartDate, 
        h.EndDate, 
        COUNT(weekends.ID) AS Weekends
FROM @HistoryLog h
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  c.ID,
            c.[Date] AS SatDate,
            DATEADD(DAY,1,c.[Date]) AS SunDate
    FROM @Calendar c
    WHERE c.[DayOfWeek] = 'Saturday'
) weekends ON h.StartDate BETWEEN weekends.SatDate AND weekends.SunDate
           OR h.EndDate BETWEEN weekends.SatDate AND weekends.SunDate
           OR (h.StartDate <= weekends.SatDate AND h.EndDate >= weekends.SunDate)
GROUP BY h.ID, h.[Status], h.StartDate, h.EndDate
```